# How to use Random() to draw images on random place in JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, animation, random

I'm working on a game where you need to click a mouse/rat, after clicking it you get 1 point and the mouse/rat will disappear

How to make the mouse image appear on different places?

My gamescreen looks like this:
[image: mouse catch game]

And my code for this page looks like:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Gamescreen extends JPanel implements Runnable {
        public String Gamestatus = "active";
        private Thread thread;
        //public Main game;

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(background, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), null);
        g.drawImage(mouse, 10, 10, null);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        Image background, muisje;
        JTextField input;
        JButton guess;
        JButton menu;

        Gamescreen() {
        setLayout(null);

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("assets/achtergrondspel.png"));
        background = icon.getImage();       

        ImageIcon icon2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("assets/muisje.png"));
        mouse = icon2.getImage();    

        //Get the default toolkit  
        Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();  

        //Load an image for the cursor  
        Image image = toolkit.getImage("src/assets/hand.png");  

        //Create the hotspot for the cursor  
        Point hotSpot = new Point(0,0);

        //Create the custom cursor  
        Cursor cursor = toolkit.createCustomCursor(image, hotSpot, "Hand");

        //Use the custom cursor  
        setCursor(cursor);

        // setLayout( null );

        // Input field
        input = new JTextField(10);
        input.setLayout(null);
        input.setBounds(150, 474, 290, 60); // change position at bottom of screen is int 1

        // Button for guess
        guess = new JButton("Raden");
        guess.setLayout(null);
        guess.setBounds(10, 474, 130, 60);
        guess.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 20));
        guess.setForeground(Color.white);
        guess.setBackground(new Color(46, 204, 113));
        guess.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 60));

        // Menu button
        menu = new JButton("Menu");
        menu.setLayout(null);
        menu.setBounds(450, 474, 130, 60);
        menu.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 20));
        menu.setForeground(Color.white);
        menu.setBackground(new Color(46, 204, 113));
        menu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130, 60));

        // add to screen
        add(input);
        //add(guess);
        add(menu);

        menu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String i = invoer.getText();
        System.out.println("Er is gedrukt! " + i);
                }
            });
        }

        public void start(){
            thread = new Thread(this,"gameloop");
            thread.start();
        }

        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            while(Gamestatus=="active"){
                System.out.println("Gameloop works");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: If you can translate some of the terms you use to English, that might be helpful. But generally, what you do is `x = random * width` and `y = random * height` where `random` is a value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Translated all dutch words to english.

Comment: `while(Gamestatus=="active")` - [HDICSIJ](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F513832%2Fhow-do-i-compare-strings-in-java&ei=qNLfUuXIK6iZiQftxYDYBQ&usg=AFQjCNE-bfxh2nRVFgcvyJyfOtbFkVXyCw&bvm=bv.59568121,d.aGc)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a method like this to create a random number in a specific range:

```
public int random(int min, int max) {

   int range = (max - min) + 1;     
   return (int)(Math.random() * range) + min;
}
```

Comment: And then: `g.drawImage(mouse, random(0, this.getWidth()), random(0, this.getHeight()), null);`

Comment: And you have to consider the size of the mose aswell

Comment: Ah yeah, true.. `random(0, this.getWidth() - mouse.getWidth())` I think? Could you add all that to your answer? `:)`

Comment: The mouse get's a fixed size. Only the position op the mouse has to change.

Comment: Yes but if you don't calculate the mouse size to the new position it might land outside the "play area".

Comment: Yeah, that another little question: as you can see in the image I have a playfield and a blue bar with a button. It's actually a background image, so now when I randomly draw the mouse on the field it's painted across the whole JPanel. I want to limit that to only the 'wood' part of the image.

Comment: Also because the mouse is drawn outside the panel.

Comment: You should add the wooden background as it's own component. 
This gives you the possibility to work only with the "play field".
Then you can use the bounds of the background image subtracted with the bounds of your mouse to place it at the right position.

If you don't subtract the position of the mouse it could end up at a position like this: http://puu.sh/6uqXj.jpg